# Angular accessing cookies within controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

```
angular.module('site.controllers', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller("LoginController", ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", function($scope, $http, $cookies){
        debugger; // can access $cookies here
        $scope.login = function(){
            debugger; // ReferenceError: $cookies is not defined
            var credentials = {
                'username': $scope.username,
                'password': $scope.password
            };
            $http.post('/login', credentials)
                .success( function(data, status, headers, config){
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[2];
                })
                .error( function(data, status, headers, config){
                    debugger;
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[2];
                //TODO: info for user that login failed
                });
        };
    }])
;
```

I have no idea why $cookies service is available in LoginController direct body, but it is not available in LoginController's login function.

$scope and $http are available in both places, however the $cookies service is problematic.

These files are included in HTML head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is accessible within the login method, as long you use it. If you try to see the data by just using `debugger`, then you would not get it in debugging console. This i think is because the js engine did not create closure since you had not referenced the property within the login method.

Try to do `console.log($cookies)` inside login method.

Comment: You're right. When I use $cookies within login method I can access it in debugger.

Comment: OMG, thank you! I thought I was losing my freaking mind. =)

Comment: @Chandermani  - You are GEM.  I was about to throw my laptop away :)